# How to retrieve title of action bar and assign it to text view?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, textview, android-actionbar

How to retrieve title of Action bar and assign it to text view?

I tried below code but it's not working...

**Code:**

```
t1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textview1);
t1.setText(getActivity().getActionBar().getTitle().toString());
```

[image: [1]: https://i.imgur.com/I5DFV.jpg "tooltip"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for java:

```
getActivity().getTitle()
```

for kotlin:

```
activity.title
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the title from Support ActionBar, Use below code.

```
YourActivity.this.getSupportActionBar().getTitle();
```